# Blocking Show Event Of A Form;

Tags: c#, forms, show

I'm trying to write a custom dialog.Everything is good but I don't want my Dialog be callable with Show() event.Anyway to block this ?

Comment: I'm asking about to block Show(), only allow to use ShowDialog() for a specific form.

Comment: What reason do you have to prohibit it?  If someone wants to show the form modelessly what problems will it cause?

Comment: If your class inherits from System.Windows.Forms, I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like OpenFileDialog which hasnt got Show.

Comment: You could derive the method, and leave the body empty. The method will still be visible but will do nothing

Comment: I think if you realy want to block it, Can you derive from a form, and override the Show method with the `new` keyword and throw an exception when it's called?

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih It's not `virtual`, so no, you can't do that.

Comment: If you do that then instead of having a is-a relationship just have a has-a relationship.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen See previous comment; `Show` isn't virtual, so you can't override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class inherits from `Form` it's not possible.  `Show` is not virtual, so you can't override it.  You should shadow it, and have it throw an exception or call `ShowDialog` internally (there is no way to remove it as an option entirely), but then any caller that just types the variable as a `Form` can still call `Show`, bypassing your implementation.

The only option available to you would be for your class to not inherit from `Form`.  You'd need to design your type to use composition rather than inheritance.  Have a `Form` property within your type's definition, and manipulate it, add controls to it, etc. as you might normally manipulate the type itself.

You would need to explicitly create members for whatever functionality that you want to expose externally, redirecting the appropriate calls to the encapsulated form (for methods such as `ShowDialog`).

Comment: Got it now. Good answer btw +1

Comment: Well what about calling ShowDialog when Show called ?

Comment: @TCBurakAvcı You could do that *if `Show` was virtual*.  But it's not, so you can't.  You could shadow it, as I said in my answer, but that's not reliable; it can be worked around.

Comment: @TCBurakAvcı You define a new method with the same name, and use the `new` operator.  As I've said any number of times now though, that's not a reliable mechanism, and is likely to just cause you grief, so I strongly discourage you from trying to do that (at least in this context).

Comment: Ok it is pointless if im trying to block something that contains Windows.Forms.Thanks to all.